# Multiple datepicker in same page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm very beginner in JS but I managed to glue such a code. Works great for one input:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="1" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" >
```

```js
      $('#date').datepicker({
    todayBtn: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
 
    }); 
 
 $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
              .on("changeDate", function(e) {
                  var datetime = $("#date").datepicker("getDate").toISOString();
      var datetime2 = e.format();
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: 'test4.php',
                      data: { 
        name : '<?php echo $exvar;?>',
        date2 : datetime2
    },
              });
});
```

How to add more inputs, it will probably be like that:

```html
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_1" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_2" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_3" />
```

What to change in JS so that both datepicker and AJAX work correctly. How to read variable in AJAX, which specifically the datepicker reads. Thanks very much. Szymon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared CSS class ("datepick" in your code) to apply the datepicker and the change event to all the textboxes simultaneously. Then within the event handler you can use `this` to refer to the specific textbox which triggered the event.

P.S. As far as I know there's no "changeDate" event (unless you've defined some custom one outside this code), and the supplied `e` event does not have a format() method. I have assumed you actually want the value from the datepicker so I've used that in your ajax call instead. I've also logged it to the console so it's visible in this demo. You also only need to call the "datepicker" function once:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepick').datepicker({
    todayBtn: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  }).on("change", function(e) {
    var datetime = $(this).datepicker("getDate").toISOString();
    console.log(datetime);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'test4.php',
      data: {
        name: '<?php echo $exvar;?>',
        date2: datetime
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_1" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_2" />
<input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_3" />
```

Comment: @SzymonKowal no problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the question so that it turns green) - thanks.